# Error in installing the Blackberry Application

Tags: blackberry

I have a application in blackberry and I am installing it device.When I import the .alx file from Blackberry workspace then it installed successfully but when I put up these 2 files(.alx and .cod) in separate folder then error occurred as here

[image]

I was testing this with my application.
But be to sure I simply imported the sample from eclipse workspace of AutoCompleteFieldDemo and put the .alx and .cod file in same folder. 
The both these file can be seen here http://dineshchandra.tk/shopclaver/themes/dark/build/
named as 
AutoCompleteFieldDemo.alx
AutoCompleteFieldDemo.cod

Please suggest where I am missing .

Comment: Can you confirm that the only difference between the two is the location of the alx and cod?  In one case they are in the deliverables folder for your Eclipse, in another they are in an external folder?  Can you show us the contents of the alx?  Rename your app if that is appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alx provided contains this:

```
    <fileset Java="1.55" _blackberryVersion="[7.1.0)">
        <directory >
            7.1.0
        </directory>
        <files >
            AutoCompleteFieldDemo.cod
        </files>
    </fileset>
```

The fileset blackberryVersion attribute is indicating that the files are applicable to OS 7.1+.  The directory tag indicates that any files will be in the directory 7.1.0 relative to the current directory. The files tag contains the files.

Looking at this, there are two potential explanations for what you are seeing

1. the device you are attempting to load this on is not running OS 7.1 or later
2. you have put the cod in the same directory as the alx, not the
   subdirectory /7.1.0.

Personally I suspect the directory and I would remove the directory element from the alx.

You will find more about the alx file attributes here:
http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/7693/Elements_and_attributes_for_alx_files_513046_11.jsp
I tried find a more current version of this documentation but failed after a quick look.  The format has not changed, so this should provide you with any additional information you need.

Comment: It was the directory problem.I deleted it and put up these two files in same folder and apps installed successfully .Thanks @Peter